# Get maximum key from SortedDictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, tree, sorteddictionary

I have a `SortedDictionary<int, TValue>` and would like to get the maximum `int` key out of it as efficiently as possible (and from that retrieve the value). Since `SortedDictionary` implements a binary tree I should be able to do that in `O(log n)`.

I am aware of the `Max()` method. However it's a Linq method. Does that mean using `Max()` will result in a `O(n)` operation?

Comment: Did you measure?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to get the maximum key in less than O(n) using the public API. You could probably do it in O(log n) by using Reflection to dig into the nodes of the private SortedSet object, but obviously a future version of the .NET Framework might break your code.